# how to pass data to view without controller

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

recently I add a nugget package to one of my projects
**project type is MVC and framework .NetFramwork 4.6.1**
namely **NotFoundMVC** By Andrew Davey
its add a ***view*** (NotFound.cshtml) to my shared folder
**this package don't add any controller to my project** but I need pass data to view for
(layout.cshtml) File How should I pass data to a view that don't have Controller

Comment: MVC has controller based routing. So, it is better to create a controller.

Comment: you mean i can add controller for the view that add by nugget  I Will Test this